# laravel undefined variable, array_where

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5

```
private function delete_read($id)
{
    $unread = unserialize(Auth::user()->unread);

    if (in_array($id, $unread))
    {
        $new = array_where($unread, function ($key, $value) {
            return $value != $id;
        });

        dd($new);
    }


}
```

I'm trying to delete read post from an unread posts list. The above codes give me an `Undefined variable: id` error, which refers to this line of code: `return $value != $id;`

So my question is how to pass variables into `array_where` method?

BTW, is there any better way to delete given elements from an array, other than `unset`? Or would `unset` be better than my `array_where` approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `$id` was defined outside of the callback function you pass into `array_where()` this variable is out of scope and won't be available by default.  However, you can try the `use` keyword to force `$id` to be in scope:

```
if (in_array($id, $unread))
{
    $new = array_where($unread, function ($key, $value) use ($id) {
        return $value != $id;
    });

    dd($new);
}
```

Comment: Nice answer! Thank you very much